# Hyperledger Composer Create Card Data in Client to Send Import Request

Tags: javascript, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm currently trying to create a blockchain application with hyperledger composer.

I have implemented the backend and frontend and got my application working with my participants submitting transactions as the admin.

So I started implementing google oauth passport so they could submit transactions as themselves.

As per this article [here](https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc), I created two servers, one to run on single user to take commands such as creating participants and issuing identities, and one to run on multi user mode to import cards and set defaults to those cards.

I set up my multi user server using [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) article. In short, create a mutli user server using google authentication that runs in a docker container.

My question is: how do I create a .card file in my frontend javascript that I can send in a POST request to my multi user server?

The card file I receive from the post request to issue an identity does not have the docker host names. So I am currently trying to hard code the connection.json for the card as it doesn't change (except for  the hostnames that I'm editing) and the metadata.json file by grabbing the user id and enrollment secret from the text of the card received from issuing the identity.

Does anyone know how I can wrap that into a .card file and send a post request to my server?

I have tried making them both JSONs and putting them in a blob, creating files with the data and putting those in a blob, and creating files with the data and putting them in a FormData object. I always get the error: `Error: bad content-type header, no multipart boundary` error.

Any suggestions and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First: code to create/export a card (incl ping the network to download cert/key creds)  to local file store in JS -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#card-api-errors--resolutions. As for connection profile  - you could use something like the `config` [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)  to source it? eg `let connectionProfile = config.get('connectionProfile'); const idCardData = new IdCard(metadata, connectionProfile);`

Comment: To access the connection profile from [IdCard](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/common-idcard) see an example in this [blog](https://medium.com/coinmonks/hyperledger-composer-api-for-managing-business-network-cards-80f215db27f7) . It would require someone 'issuer' authority in Composer to issue the identity. You would `.connect` with this business network card in your JS and its connection profile info would already be available to you (if that's what you want) and in the card that would be issued, once exported.